# Unity roll-a-ball - ball wont roll faster than 3.8... sometimes

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'v been working on the roll-a-ball project from the learn section. I recently added a "Speed" text field and I noticed that when I first start playing, if press W or S then the speed will not go above 3.8 (or below -3.8). If I go left or right just a hair, this will fix the problem and I can move with W and S as normal. The same fix happens if I bump the ball into a wall. The glitch also does not occur if I start the ball out at (.0000001, .5, 0) in the editor instead of (0, .5, 0). Just incase I somehow screwed the code up I'll paste it below.

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.UI;
 using System.Collections;

 public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {
     public float moveSpeed;
     public float accelSpeed;
     private int pickupCount;
     public Text countText;
     public Text winText;
     public Text speedGage;

     void Start(){
         pickupCount = 0;
         setCountText();
         winText.text = "";
         speedGage.text = "0";
     }
     void FixedUpdate(){
         updateMovement();

     }
     void updateMovement(){
         float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
         float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
         Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal,0,moveVertical);
         rigidbody.AddForce(movement * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
         speedGage.text = rigidbody.velocity.ToString();
     }
     void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
         if(other.gameObject.tag == "PickUp"){
             other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
             pickupCount += 1;
             setCountText();
         }
     }
     void setCountText(){
         countText.text = "Count: " + pickupCount.ToString();
         if(pickupCount == 16){
             winText.text = "You Win!";
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has been here for a while with no answer posted, so if you haven't found a solution yet or if someone else may find themselves searching for an answer...

Within the rigidbody.AddForce call, the movement vector is multiplied by movespeed and Time.deltaTime, which makes for an incredibly small value.  Try changing it to something like this:

```
rigidbody.AddForce(movement * movespeed, Forcemode.Force);
```

or if you want to ignore the mass of the ball for sudden direction changes use Forcemode.VelocityChange.

Time is already factored into rigidbody.AddForce, as the results will unfold into the following physics steps due to the effect on velocity, as long as the ball doesn't get stuck on an obstacle.